# Update an attribute of an existing entity in Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

This is my first time using Core Data and I'm trying to figure out how to update an attribute on an entity that has already been created.

I have an app that when a Person entity is created there is also a entity created called Statement with a type of To Many. The Statement entity has several attributes. I would like to be able to update one of these attributes at a certain point in my apps lifecycle. I'm just not sure how to go about this. I know I need to figure how out which Person entity it is I want to update, and after I get the person I need to target the specific attribute of the Statement entity. I think this is where I might use a predicate, but I'm still not 100% sure on how they work. I'm just not sure where to start to solve my issues. Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty specific question but the 2nd paragraph question seems to have some much broader implications. The short of it is, you should sub-class a NSManagedObject to match your entity and then save the NSManagedObjectContext in which you're working with. The long of it is I suggest getting familiar with all of Core Data, it's super powerful and awesome and some examples will make things more apparent.

Comment: thanks @thefredelement. I am using a subclass of NSManagedObject, I'm just not sure how to add it back into the stack at the proper index.

Comment: you don't need to, after you update a property on the object you just need to save the context.